# PHP require_once or include_once nesting

Tags: php

Directory structure,

- A.php
- folder

  - B.php
  - C.php

A.php includes B.php and B.php includes C.php.

But B.php needs to include C.php relative to A.php. Is there any way I can include C.php relative to B.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include using `__DIR__` or `dirname(__FILE__)`.

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

> The directory of the file. If used
>   inside an include, the directory of
>   the included file is returned. This is
>   equivalent to `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

#### A.PHP

```
include_once(__DIR__.'/folder/B.php');
include_once(__DIR__.'/folder/C.php');
```

#### B.php

```
include_once(__DIR__.'/A.php');
```